# compare two string shortcut in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to compare two string in asp.net means easily we can compare two string like==>

```
if(Path.GetExtension(fileupload1.FileName).ToLower() == ".png" || Path.GetExtension(fileupload1.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg")
```

but is there any way to do this like i wnats to do something like that=>

```
if((Path.GetExtension(fileupload1.FileName).ToLower()) == ".png" || ".jpeg")
```

but it gives me error.can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried with List of string with Contains method ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(new String[] { ".png", ".jpeg" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileupload1.FileName).ToLower()))
{
    Console.WriteLine("found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static readonly string[] _validExtensions = {".jpg",".png"}; 

public static bool IsImageExtension(string ext)
{
        return _validExtensions.Contains(ext);
}
```

and use it like

```
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload1.FileName);
 if (IsImageExtension(ext){

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "chain" `||` like that. You would have to do like in your first example or pretty it up with some LINQ.

```
var fileTypes = new List<string> { ".png", ".jpeg" };
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload1.FileName);
if (fileTypes.Any(e => e.Equals(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))){
      //something here
}
```

This has the advantage over `Contains` in that you can do a case-insensitive match (no need to normalize everything to upper or lower case).

Alternatively you could pass a [`StringComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) to the overload of [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an Equality Comparer.

```
var fileTypes = new List<string> { ".png", ".jpeg" };
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload1.FileName);
if (fileTypes.Contains(ext, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
      // do stuff here
}
```